# PHPWord does not work in IIS server

Tags: exception, ms-word, fatal-error, phpword

I am using [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/documentation), and it works perfectly in windows 7, linux server. But in windows NT IIS/6.0 server, there is error message showing like this

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file.' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\PHPWord\PHPWord\Template.php:109 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\PHPWord\PHPWord\paid.php(36): PHPWord_Template->save('test.docx') #1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\PHPWord\PHPWord\letter.php(6): include_once('C:\inetpub\wwwr...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\PHPWord\PHPWord\Template.php on line 109

The following code is creating the error:

> require_once 'PHPWord/PHPWord.php';
>
> $PHPWord = new PHPWord(); //digup($row_case);
>
> $filename = 'test';
>
> $document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('test-temp.docx');
>
> $document->setValue('date', date('F d, Y'));
>
> $document->setValue('weekday', date('l')); $document->setValue('time',
>   date('H:i'));
>
> $document->save($filename.'.docx');

Is there anything that I have to install in the server or anything can be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: What code is throwing the error?

Comment: @EmilVikström I have edited the the question with the code that is throwing the error

Thanks for your concern

Comment: It's still not complete. You need to add the code that is *actually* throwing the error (at least row 109 from Template.php, but there may be other relevant files as well). Try to read the code yourself as well and try to figure out *why* it throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\PHPWord\PHPWord\Template.php
```

Add this line after line 108:

```
print $this->_objZip->getStatusString();
```

This should print an human readable reason why the zip file can't be closed.

One of the most common reasons is a missing file or a temporary directory that's not accessible.